# Core Data file storage

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have been working on core data, for storing files and fetching it, no problem in running the application, But i can't find where the datas are being stored?

Searched and found that,the storage will be in the following location of our system, `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/3BF8A4B3-4959-4D8F-AC12-DB8EF4C3B6E1/Library/YourAppName.sqlite`

But in my Mac i cant get the iPhone Simulator folder.

Then how could i see where my file is being saved ?

Answer (score 2):

Open finder and use this command,

```
Command+shift+g
```

then

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```

you can locate the simulator

Comment: Thanks @Erik, found the exact folder, which I need.